# Unable to Run Build on Hudson Using Git

Tags: git, hudson

I configured every thing and tried to run the build i am getting the below error 
could anyone help me out on this .

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Documents and Settings\Pradeep\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace -  hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@6ea3fe
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / C:\Documents and Settings\Pradeep\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@6ea3fe
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:xxxx/xxx.git
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin fetch -t git@github.com:xxxx/xxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin" (in directory "C:\Documents and Settings\Pradeep\.hudson\jobs\test\workspace"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:887)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:845)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:845)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:622)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1479)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:507)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1366)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)
```

Comment: may be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760287/hudson-wont-fetch-from-git

Comment: Looks like incorrectly configured path to git binary. It's trying to run `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and should be runnin `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`.

Comment: @Balaswamyvaddeman: The error in that question happens later than this one. Does not seem to be the same one.

Comment: Github is denying access to the repository and it cannot be checked out. Is this a private repository?

Comment: Yes this is a private repository

Comment: I am getting this error for the very first case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a private repository, hudson is unable to connect as the ssh-key used is using a paraphrase for authenticating, since there is no way to insert the authentication key hudson fails.

However, before trying the step below - cf - [Jenkins can not clone Git repository over Git/SSH on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850395/jenkins-can-not-clone-git-repository-over-git-ssh-on-windows) . The same question asked in stackoverflow, the user had success using git.cmd rather than git.exe on hudson, can you also try the same.

If that does not resolve, please try by removing the paraphrase from your ssh-key and retrying. cf - http://www.lucasward.net/2011/05/tips-for-connecting-to-github-private.html

Finally, an alternative method using hooks - http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2011/09/20/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github

Comment: Which one worked, git.cmd or ssh-key with no paraphrase? Just want to get that on the comments so that if people come across this, they can see what worked. Thanks

Comment: I tried to install hudson on ubuntu , but unable to get access private repos , how do i fix this issue on a linux system ?

Comment: Whats the error? In ubuntu run the following to generate the ssh-key `ssh-keygen -t RSA` and press enter for everything. It should create a ssh-key without paraphrase

Comment: to generate the ssh key i followed the steps as mentioned in http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/ 
when prompted for passphrases i gave empty string .. but this did not work for me

Comment: As you mentioned above to generate ssh-key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa ` but still i am unable to get it work with hudson 
getting the below error on building it `Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone git@github.com:rampelli/test.git
ERROR: Cause: Exception caught during execution of fetch command
Trying next repository
ERROR: Could not clone repository
FATAL: Could not clone `

Comment: If you try via command line does it work? `git clone <your repository url>`. It looks like the git url is not correct.