# Hudson failed to clone git repository + Hudson PORT change

Tags: git, continuous-integration, hudson, fedora

Today I started using hudson for continuous integration. I installed it on my windows machine and configured everything as described in the book about installation and configuration. I am using its git plugin to fetch from git repository and build.

**My 1st problem is the same as this one**

[Unable to Run Build on Hudson Using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786023/unable-to-run-build-on-hudson-using-git)

The git repository from where i want to clone is a private repository, which uses shh key without paraphrase. The above question suggested the solution to remove the paraphrase which in my case does not exists at all.

I searched and tried some other solutions as well but no success.

Following is the trace log

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\UIQBAL\.hudson\jobs\Test\workspace -   hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@14be0c6
Using strategy: Default
Checkout:workspace / C:\Users\UIQBAL\.hudson\jobs\Test\workspace -  hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@14be0c6
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@vrtbichler11.informatik.tu-muenchen.de:wsc18
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files   (x86)\SmartGitHg 4.5\git\bin\git.exe fetch -t git@vrtbichler11.informatik.tu-    muenchen.de:wsc18 +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 null
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:744)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:706)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:193)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.fetch(GitAPI.java:960)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:1617)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$900(GitSCM.java:107)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:954)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:919)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:791)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:773)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:919)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:698)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1515)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:521)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:428)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
 Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:353)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.join(Proc.java:222)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:273)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:731)
... 18 more
  ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
  FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not fetch from any repository
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:961)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$3.invoke(GitSCM.java:919)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:791)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:773)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.gerRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:919)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:698)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1515)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:521)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:428)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1390)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:40)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
```

Is there a way to provide my git repository shh key to hudson ?

**2nd Problem:** I also installed hudson on my VM, and it runs on port 8080 but my tomcat is also running on port 8080. I tried to change the port of hudson but no success, For windows it is in hudson.xml but my VM is running on fedora.

What I tried to change the port is

```
stop hudson
vi /etc/sysconfig/hudson 
start hudson
check to see on which port hudson is running and it gives httpPort=12398 

 [root@wsc18 bin]# ps -ef| grep hudson | grep Port
 root     22604 22602  0 04:51 ?        00:00:00 runuser -s /bin/bash hudson -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -  DHUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/hudson -jar /usr/lib/hudson/hudson.war -- logfile=/var/log/hudson/hudson.log --daemon --httpPort=12398 --debug=5 -- handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
 hudson   22607 22604  0 04:51 ?        00:00:00 bash -c ulimit -S -c 0 >/dev/null 2>&1  ; /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DHUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/hudson -jar  /usr/lib/hudson/hudson.war --logfile=/var/log/hudson/hudson.log --daemon --httpPort=12398 - -debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
 hudson   22608 22607 14 04:51 ?        00:00:07 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true   -DHUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/hudson -jar /usr/lib/hudson/hudson.war -- logfile=/var/log/hudson/hudson.log --daemon --httpPort=12398 --debug=5 -- handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

when I open it on vmlocalhost:12398 it does not respond.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

2nd Problem is solved by adding entry for the port 12398 in iptables

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve your 1st Problem by adding windows Environment Variable.

```
Name: HOME
Value: $USERPROFILE
```

for more info go this URL http://element34.ca/blog/jenkins-remote-windows-nodes-and-private-github-repos